# matrix twig loop rows - odd one color and even alternating colors

Tags: matrix, twig, craftcms

I'm trying to loop through rows that result in the following:

```
row 1 - white
row 2 - gray
row 3 - white
row 4 - navy
row 5 - white
row 6 - gray 
row 7 - white
row 8 - navy
```

And etc...

I have the following, which obviously only works for the first 5 rows, but can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this:

```
{% if loop.index is odd %}
    <div id="{{ target }}" class="band white">
{% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
    <div id="{{ target }}" class="band gray">
{% elseif loop.index == 4 %}
    <div id="{{ target }}" class="band navy">
{% endif %}
```

any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the modulo operator `%` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the [cycle](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html) function, and use it like this:

```
class="band {{ cycle(["white", "gray", "white", "beige"], loop.index0) }}"
```